# Separation of variables for fourth order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How do I solve:

$$u_t = -u_{xxxx} + \pi^2u_{xx},$$ 
with BCs: $u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=u_{xxx}(0,t)=u_{xxx}(1,t)=0$ and initial condition $u(x,0)=\cos(\pi x)$.

We have been told that we can use separation of variables however I can't seem to get the required solution $\cos(\pi x)\exp(-2\pi^4t)$.

Comment: Enclose your math in \$$\dotsc$\$ to make your post more readable.  Use $\{\dotsc\}$. In other words learn some basic TeX.

Comment: You may want to do some Fourier transforms, to get an ordinary differential equations before attempting separation of variables. Alternatively (which is basically the same), you write $u(x,t)$ as a time-dependent coefficients Fourier series in $x$.

Comment: pea91, the separation of variables thing is huge I think since it means the solution "u is a product in which the dependence of u on x, t is separated". @KittyL shows how it's done. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume $u=X(x)T(t)$, you will get

$$XT'=-X^{(4)}T+\pi^2X''T=T(-X^{(4)}+\pi^2X'')$$
$$\frac{X}{-X^{(4)}+\pi^2X''}=\frac{T}{T'}$$

Then you can continue from there.

Comment: Equate each side to $- \lambda$ or something?

Comment: @Jack: Yes. They would be constant.

Comment: I did do that however I struggled solving the differential equations for each case of lambda. For example lambda less than zero trying to solve the characteristic equation of the DE I get a square root inside a square root!

Comment: @pea91: If you mean the $X$ part, you don't need to solve for that. Solve the $T$ part first and the initial condition will give you the $X$ part.

Comment: Solving for $T$ I get $T$=cos(pi*x)exp(lambda*t)/$X$. How do I then use my $X$ Equation to calculate that lambda=-2pi^4, so I get the correct solution?

Comment: @pea91: Did you mean $T=\cos{(\pi x)}e^{(\lambda t)}$? There shouldn't be $X$ anymore. Now plug this back into the original equation. You should be able to find $\lambda$.